# Assign onfocus to DOM elements in runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, runtime, onfocus

I am interested in assigning onfocus or other similar functions to a DOM elements in runtime.

General Case:

```
<input type="text" id="box" onfocus="inputFocused()"/>
```

Runtime Assignment Case:

```
<input type="text" id="box"/>
```

And in the script

```
$('#box').onfocus = inputFocused();
```

`inputFocused()` is nothing more than a simple function. It appears not working properly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use it as :

```
$('#box').on('focus',inputFocused);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#box').on('focus',inputFocused);

function inputFocused(){
  alert('focused');  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="box"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
$('#box').onfocus = inputFocused();
```

with:

```
$('#box').focus(inputFocused);
```

It's the jquery correct syntax. From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/focus/):

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "focus", handler ) ...